# Google Cloud Messaging - api keys - rebrand application

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to ask the following:

If I registered an application and I got the **API KEYS** and I want to **re brand an application**" 
Could I still use the same credentials that Ive obtained when creating Google Cloud API with the original name of the project?

I would also like to mention I am talking **about GCM on the CLIENT SIDE**.
I did some research on the internet, but I haven't found an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API project id and API key are not tied to any Android app. You can even use the same API key to send notifications to different apps.

Therefore you can rename your app and still use the same API project id and API key.